# zsh (z shell) numpad/numlock doesn't work

Tags: zsh

I just upgraded to zsh/oh-my-zsh. Almost immediately I notice on my machine that the 10-digit numpad is not working. It was working in bash and fish shell.

Oddly, if I hold down the fn/function key it acts like numlock and works, but it doesn't "lock" and I would have to keep holding down fn to type out the numbers.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The numpad key do not send the same key symbols as the 'normal' number key in the top row. For example: The numpad-1-key sends `KP_1` while the 1-key just sends `1`.

Some terminals automatically remap the numpad key to send the same codes to the shell. Also, some shells (for example `bash`) just interprete the numpad keys like their equivalents in the main block.

`zsh` does not do the mapping automatically, but you can use `bindkey` to do the mapping on your own. I have the following in my `~/.zshrc` to get the keypad working:

```
# Keypad
# 0 . Enter
bindkey -s "^[Op" "0"
bindkey -s "^[Ol" "."
bindkey -s "^[OM" "^M"
# 1 2 3
bindkey -s "^[Oq" "1"
bindkey -s "^[Or" "2"
bindkey -s "^[Os" "3"
# 4 5 6
bindkey -s "^[Ot" "4"
bindkey -s "^[Ou" "5"
bindkey -s "^[Ov" "6"
# 7 8 9
bindkey -s "^[Ow" "7"
bindkey -s "^[Ox" "8"
bindkey -s "^[Oy" "9"
# + -  * /
bindkey -s "^[Ok" "+"
bindkey -s "^[Om" "-"
bindkey -s "^[Oj" "*"
bindkey -s "^[Oo" "/"
```

`bindkey -s in-string out-string` binds `in-string` to `out-string`. If `in-string` is typed `out-string` is pushed back and treated as input.

The actual codes (for example `^[Oq`) may be different on your system. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by the key in question to get the code for your terminal.

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked perfectly for me and the `Ctrl` + `v` tip is great!

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful but some keys were missing for the Apple USB keyboard. This is the key binding for Apple Keyboard:  # Keypad
# 0 . Enter
bindkey -s "^[Op" "0"
bindkey -s "^[On" "."
bindkey -s "^[OM" "^M"
# 1 2 3
bindkey -s "^[Oq" "1"
bindkey -s "^[Or" "2"
bindkey -s "^[Os" "3"
# 4 5 6
bindkey -s "^[Ot" "4"
bindkey -s "^[Ou" "5"
bindkey -s "^[Ov" "6"
# 7 8 9
bindkey -s "^[Ow" "7"
bindkey -s "^[Ox" "8"
bindkey -s "^[Oy" "9"
# + -  * /
bindkey -s "^[Ok" "+"
bindkey -s "^[Om" "-"
bindkey -s "^[Oj" "*"
bindkey -s "^[Oo" "/"
bindkey -s "^[OX" "="

Comment: The manual for this: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Key-Binding.html#Key-Binding

Comment: and this is good too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042685/list-of-zsh-bindkey-commands

Comment: https://github.com/krowe/kshrc-k800-keybindings Made this based off this answer.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this about 100 times.

Answer (score 23):

To complete the answer that @adaephon gave, the following are the correct bindings for the Apple USB keyboard (A1243). These need to be added to `~/.zshrc`.

```
# Fix numeric keypad
# 0 . Enter
bindkey -s "^[Op" "0"
bindkey -s "^[On" "."
bindkey -s "^[OM" "^M"
# 1 2 3
bindkey -s "^[Oq" "1"
bindkey -s "^[Or" "2"
bindkey -s "^[Os" "3"
# 4 5 6
bindkey -s "^[Ot" "4"
bindkey -s "^[Ou" "5"
bindkey -s "^[Ov" "6"
# 7 8 9
bindkey -s "^[Ow" "7"
bindkey -s "^[Ox" "8"
bindkey -s "^[Oy" "9"
# + -  * / =
bindkey -s "^[Ol" "+"
bindkey -s "^[Om" "-"
bindkey -s "^[Oj" "*"
bindkey -s "^[Oo" "/"
bindkey -s "^[OX" "="
```

Comment: Robin, could you expand your answer to include where OP should input this information to correct their problem?

Comment: This worked for me except `+` (had to use `bindkey -s "^[Ok" "+"`) and `=` (missing `bindkey -s "^[OX" "="`)

Answer (score 8):

On MacOS Catalina with A1843 Apple Keyboard:

I set the Terminal configuration to **ansi**. It works with all the keys.

No keybindings needed.

[image: Terminal.app Screenshot]

[image: iTerm Screenshot]

Comment: This worked great! I added an iTerm screenshot.

Comment: Good that you have added iTerm too, worked for me as well, no binding was needed.

Answer (score 4):

Also complementing answer from @adaephon. Here is what I had to use for my Dell Desktop, might be of help. Just add it in your .zshrc file.

(BTW dont add bindings from all answers, you should just have one binding per key)

```
# Keypad
# 0 . Enter
bindkey -s "^[Op" "0"
bindkey -s "^[On" "."
bindkey -s "^[OM" "^M"
# 1 2 3
bindkey -s "^[Oq" "1"
bindkey -s "^[Or" "2"
bindkey -s "^[Os" "3"
# 4 5 6
bindkey -s "^[Ot" "4"
bindkey -s "^[Ou" "5"
bindkey -s "^[Ov" "6"
# 7 8 9
bindkey -s "^[Ow" "7"
bindkey -s "^[Ox" "8"
bindkey -s "^[Oy" "9"
# + -  * /
bindkey -s "^[OQ" "/"
bindkey -s "^[OR" "*"
bindkey -s "^[OS" "-"
bindkey -s "^[Ol" "+"
#END Keypad
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/907695/edit) your answer to include a little guidance about what this is and how/where to use it?

Comment: This solution worked for me for zsh with windows keypad (PUTTY, with `Terminal > Keyboard > Initial state of numeric pad > Normal`)

Answer (score 4):

On my Mac OSX El Capitan, the period key is `^[0n` instead of `^[01`. Also I have a Logitech wireless keyboard for the Mac and it has an `=` sign on the numpad too. My final mapping looks like below:

```
# Keypad
# 0 . Enter
bindkey -s "^[Op" "0"
bindkey -s "^[On" "."
bindkey -s "^[OM" "^M"
# 1 2 3
bindkey -s "^[Oq" "1"
bindkey -s "^[Or" "2"
bindkey -s "^[Os" "3"
# 4 5 6
bindkey -s "^[Ot" "4"
bindkey -s "^[Ou" "5"
bindkey -s "^[Ov" "6"
# 7 8 9
bindkey -s "^[Ow" "7"
bindkey -s "^[Ox" "8"
bindkey -s "^[Oy" "9"
# + -  * / =
bindkey -s "^[Ok" "+"
bindkey -s "^[Om" "-"
bindkey -s "^[Oj" "*"
bindkey -s "^[Oo" "/"
bindkey -s "^[OX" "="
```

The solution others proposed works correctly however.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Kitty to access a linux server on SSH and that the keypad is working fine with Bash but not with ZSH, you may try adding the following in your `~/.zshrc` config file:

```
# Keypad
# 0 . Enter
bindkey -s "^[Op" "0"
bindkey -s "^[On" "."
bindkey -s "^[OM" "^M"
# 1 2 3
bindkey -s "^[Oq" "1"
bindkey -s "^[Or" "2"
bindkey -s "^[Os" "3"
# 4 5 6
bindkey -s "^[Ot" "4"
bindkey -s "^[Ou" "5"
bindkey -s "^[Ov" "6"
# 7 8 9
bindkey -s "^[Ow" "7"
bindkey -s "^[Ox" "8"
bindkey -s "^[Oy" "9"
# + -  * /
bindkey -s "^[Ol" "+"
bindkey -s "^[OS" "-"
bindkey -s "^[OR" "*"
bindkey -s "^[OQ" "/"
```

Save.
Logout and login again to reload the ZSH config, or alternatively you can type the following in your terminal:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

The keypad should now work as expected!

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: Let me disagree. Only this answer has similar codes : http://superuser.com/a/907695/351420

And I explain the context and how to use those codes, imho better than this answer.